# Mysql/php order by most popular table structure

Tags: mysql, database-design

Is there a tried and true best practice for displaying most viewed posts?
Do people normally set up a viewed table and count records?  I believe this would require a join of the posts and viewed table when retrieving data.  Is there a better way?  Thanks.

Comment: If you don't care about individual views (for example, what time the views occurred), you should create some sort of stats table that aggregates views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps create a `views` table with a unique id, post id, and IP address/unique identifier.  That way you can sort by all views/unique views.

You order by would be

```
SELECT [...], COUNT(DISTINCT(views.ip)) count
FROM posts
INNER JOIN views ON views.postid = post.id
ORDER BY count DESC
GROUP BY post.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a field called (visited) and touch it everytime someone open the page (set visited=visited+1)
So you can order by visited.

I hope it helps